# Is every true $\Pi^0_1$ statement entailed from a consistency statement of $PA$?

Tags: lo.logic

I want to prove the following.

> For every $\Pi^0_1$ statement $\forall x\phi(x)$, where $\phi(x)$ is a $\Delta^0_1$ formula, there is $e\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall x\phi(x)$ implies $W_e=PA$* and $PA+\text{$W_e$ is consistent}\vdash\forall x\phi(x)$.

The argument is inspire by an argument of Turing in his [PhD dissertation](https://www.princeton.edu/turing//alan/dissertation/) (lately rephrased in [Feferman 1962](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2964649)) to show that the transfinite progressions of adding consistency statements is sensitive on which branch we choose at the limit stage of Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$, and it is as follow.

> Fix a computable function $\sigma$ such that the range of $\sigma$ is $PA$. By recursion theorem, we can construct a partial computable function $\varphi_e$ such that
>
> $\varphi_e(n)=\begin{cases}\sigma(n),&\text{if $\forall x<n\phi(n)$},\\
> \sigma(n)\wedge\text{$W_e$ is consistent*},&\text{o.w.}\end{cases}$
>
> Since $\forall x\phi(x)$ holds, $W_e=PA$. So the statement "$W_e$ is consistent" is really "$PA$ is consistent". In the next paragraph, we prove in $PA+$"$W_e$ is consistent".
>
> Assume $\forall x\phi(x)$ fails, than $W_e=PA+$"$W_e$ is consistent". By Goedel's second incompleteness theroem, $W_e$ is not consistent. A contradiction.
>
> This finishes the argument.

My question is (1) is this argument valid, or if something is missed or misunderstood? (2) is there other reference on this and related issues?

*$W_e$ is the range of $\Phi_e$ by fixing an enumeration of Turing machines $\{\Phi_e\}_{e\in\mathbb{N}}$. $PA$ stands for Peano Arithmetic. Please forgive my abusing of notation.

Comment: I don’t understand the notation. What is $W_e$, $\Sigma_e$, and $PA^*$?

Comment: $W_e$ is the range of $\Phi_e$ by fixing an enumeration of Turing machines $\{\Phi_e\}_e$. $\Sigma_e$ is a typo (fixed), which should be $W_e$. $PA$ stands for Peano Arithmetic. I am sorry for the ambiguities.

Comment: I think the "PA$^*$" in your opener should just be PA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement you want to prove is true, and your argument works - but there's a simpler one: drop all reference to the recursion theorem and Godelian incompleteness, and just change the second clause in your definition of $\varphi_e(n)$ to "$\sigma(n)\wedge\exists x(x\not=x)$." That is, introduce an inconsistency *directly* rather than playing with deeper facts about the theory and computability.

As you say, the only way $W_e$ can be consistent is if that second case doesn't occur, and if $\forall x\phi(x)$ is indeed true then that second case never occurs and $W_e$ "is" PA.

Given the directness of this construction, I suspect that there is no explicit reference.